# Why returns apache a http 500 but does not log any errors?

Tags: apache-2.2, php, web-server, php5

On a 12 year old (web) server is still 1 old (custom) PHP application hosted. We want to shutdown this server and remove it from the rack. Unfortunately we still need the application, is not actively used anymore but needs to be available for archive purposes. The application does not support newer PHP versions than v5.2. For this reason i wanted to host the application in a docker container (https://hub.docker.com/r/kuborgh/php-5.2/dockerfile)

I started the container with `docker run --publish 9090:80 --name xxproject -v /var/docker_mounts/xxproject:/project e28e8b71a1f7` which mounts my application folder (xxproject) on the host machine the `/project` folder in the container. When i add a `index.html` into my xxproject folder on my host and browse to ip:9090 i see the expected content.

When i exchange the `index.html` with an `index.php` file (content: `Hello world`) i get a `http 500` response.

When i check the apache error logs (in the container: `docker exec -it xxproject bash`) i don't get any entry. The logs work because i can see a debug entry when i enter the website.

The `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-project.conf` (i added `LogLevel debug` in the container for test purposes):

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost

    DocumentRoot /project
    <Directory /project>
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        allow from all
    </Directory>
    LogLevel debug
</VirtualHost>
```

the only log entries in `/var/log/apache2/error.log`

```
[Thu Aug 06 06:47:00 2020] [debug] mod_deflate.c(700): [client 10.128.10.41] Zlib: Compressed 0 to 2 : URL /index.php
[Thu Aug 06 06:47:01 2020] [debug] mod_deflate.c(700): [client 10.128.10.41] Zlib: Compressed 0 to 2 : URL /index.php
```

I see the requests in the `/var/log/apache2/other_vhost_names.log`

```
172.17.0.3:80 10.128.10.41 - - [06/Aug/2020:06:47:00 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 375 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/84.0.4147.105 Safari/537.36"
172.17.0.3:80 10.128.10.41 - - [06/Aug/2020:06:47:01 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 375 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/84.0.4147.105 Safari/537.36"
```

When i check `php -a` the interactive php terminal works like expected. How can i debug this issue further? I know that php 5.2 and Ubuntu 12 is deprecated and its not recommended to still use them but this is offtopic!

=====**UPDATE 1**=====

PHP configuration in apache (already set by default for the concerning docker image). I did not made any changes to the docker container except for the changes mentioned above.

```
root@63ca87239042:/etc/apache2# grep -ri -B 2 -A 2 php .
./mods-enabled/dir.conf-<IfModule mod_dir.c>
./mods-enabled/dir.conf-
./mods-enabled/dir.conf:          DirectoryIndex index.html index.cgi index.pl index.php index.xhtml index.htm
./mods-enabled/dir.conf-
./mods-enabled/dir.conf-</IfModule>
--
./mods-enabled/php5.load:LoadModule php5_module        /usr/lib/apache2/modules/libphp5.so
--
./mods-available/dir.conf-<IfModule mod_dir.c>
./mods-available/dir.conf-
./mods-available/dir.conf:          DirectoryIndex index.html index.cgi index.pl index.php index.xhtml index.htm
./mods-available/dir.conf-
./mods-available/dir.conf-</IfModule>
--
./mods-available/php5.load:LoadModule php5_module        /usr/lib/apache2/modules/libphp5.so
--
./sites-available/default-ssl-  #     directives are used in per-directory context.
./sites-available/default-ssl-  #SSLOptions +FakeBasicAuth +ExportCertData +StrictRequire
./sites-available/default-ssl:  <FilesMatch "\.(cgi|shtml|phtml|php)$">
./sites-available/default-ssl-          SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
./sites-available/default-ssl-  </FilesMatch>
```

Comment: Maybe set `ErrorLog` explicitly in the `VirtualHost` block, re-start and re-check?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I just tried this and (unfortunately) it gets exactly the same entries as the `/var/log/apache2/error.log`, any other suggestions ?

Comment: Have you increased log verbosity in the PHP configuration?

Comment: Is there anytihing in your apache configuration concerning PHP?

Comment: @GerardH.Pille, i updated the question. I did not make PHP specific changes to the apache config files. When i need to do some, i have no clue which one as i expected that the docker image is already completely "pre-configured" to use it as webserver. Thats at least what the description of the docker image says (see link in the question)

Comment: Just to clarify, is the content of `index.php` "Hello world" as described, or is it php content like `<?php echo "Hello world"; ?>`?

Comment: @tetech, thanks, I didn't dare to ask that one.

Comment: It's really `Hello world` for test purposes though i also tried `<?php echo "Hello world"; ?>` and `<?php phpinfo(); ?>`, both with the same http 500 result. Note that an index.html with content like `Hello world` works fine. Having no `index.html` or `index.php` at all results in a `You don't have permission to access / on this server.` page.

Comment: It should be "<?php echo "Hello world"; ?> and <?php phpinfo(); ?>" to start with.   Does Apache have the right to read this file?  What errors do you have with this file?

Comment: Apache will not log in its error log if the 500 error comes from PHP. In this case you need to check PHP's error log.

Comment: @MichaelHampton, are you sure?  This is /usr/lib/apache2/modules/libphp5.so, I don't remember there was a separate PHP.

Comment: @GerardH.Pille Hm, no, I'm not sure. It's been more than a decade since I've had to deal with mod_php, except helping people get away from it. Still it should have some way to log errors in php.ini?

Comment: @MichaelHampton, IIRC the errors - maybe any output from PHP - will be in the Apache error log.  But for me too, it's been a while.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure but i thought PHP errors are also logged in the Apache log tough i checked for a separated PHP log and found some configuration options in the `/etc/php/apache2-php5.2/php.ini`, i set them like: `display_errors=On` (was Off) and `error_log = /var/log/php.log` (was commented out). After that i rebooted the container and visited the webserver in the browser, still 500 and no logs..

Comment: UPDATE: the problem is php related as `display_errors = On` turns the 500 error into a blank page. Unfortunately i cannot find any php logs. As noted in my previous comment i configured set `error_log = /var/log/php.ini` and `log_errors = On` in the `php.ini` file. In my previous comment i wrote that the 500 still existed after the changes but for some reason chrome cached the 500 page for that url or something. In edge and IE i see the 500/white page when i change the `display_errors` setting

Comment: Where did you get the php5 module?  Is it compatible with your Apache version?  Although, if it worn't, Apache would have signalled it.  No missing dependencies if you do a "ldd libphp5.so" ?

Comment: @GerardH.Pille I think the php version is compatible as it comes both together as a Docker container. (https://hub.docker.com/r/kuborgh/php-5.2/dockerfile). I tried the `lld libphp5.so` command but that one is not workng. I also tried to run `apt-get install lld`  before without any result...

Comment: It is "ldd", not "lld", or was that a double typo?

Comment: I may try to duplicate your setup.  What is your OS?

Comment: @GerardH.Pille i use Ubuntu 20.04LTS with Docker installed. To get the same container as i use, you can use `docker pull kuborgh/php-5.2`.  -- I don't know if you are familiar with docker, if not: show all available containers: `docker ps -a`, start a container: `docker run --publish 1080:80 --name som_name -v /var/host/project_folder:/project container_id_from_docker_ps` (localhost:8080), access console:  `docker exec -it some_name bash`  -- Thanks for all your effort!

Comment: I changed my answer below, I managed to run kuborgh/php-5.2 without a glitch.  I sure hope you don't make those typos (--publish 1080:80) when you're testing.  When you run "docker ps", is there more than one container up and running?

Comment: Also, repeating what I said in my answer: no way to do a "docker run" with a container id.  I'll add the error to my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe Apache doesn't know when to use the php module?   I found this [apache cwiki](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/HTTPD/PHP4AndPHP5)

```
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php .php .phtml
Action application/x-httpd-php modules/libphp5.so
```

This how I started the container:

```
docker run --publish 9090:80  -v /tmp/project:/project kuborgh/php-5.2
```

/tmp/project is world read-, write- and searchable, the first index.php I put in there was executed succesfully when I visited http://localhost:9090/.

When I try, like you, to "docker run" with a docker id,

```
docker run --publish 9090:80 --name xxproject -v /var/docker_mounts/xxproject:/project e28e8b71a1f7
```

I get an error, saying the image e28e8b71a1f7 isn't to be found.

```
$ docker ps -a
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS                      PORTS               NAMES
bddc43202735        kuborgh/php-5.2     "/usr/sbin/apache2ct…"   18 hours ago        Exited (137) 16 hours ago                       eager_ride
$ docker run --publish 9090:80  --name AmehoelA -v /tmp/project:/project bddc43202735
Unable to find image 'bddc43202735:latest' locally
docker: Error response from daemon: pull access denied for bddc43202735, repository does not exist or may require 'docker login': denied: requested access to the resource is denied.
```

Comment: I tried this as this makes sense in my opinion but unfortunately it does nothing

Comment: You did put the correct location, I hope?

Comment: Yes, `/usr/lib/apache2/modules/libphp5.so`

Comment: For some reason i could not get it working and it worked magically after removing everything (container and image) and start over again. I already removed the container but that did not work so i thing my image was broken/corrupt or something but it works now so thanks for all your effort!